# Cheerio.js .each() function is returning one large string when used with .find('a').text()

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

I am using CheerioJS to scrape a list of text from a site. I am correctly finding the text, however something strange is happening when using .each on an array of table rows.

Here is my code

```
const getTopCollections = async () => {
const response = await axios.get('https://www.nft-stats.com/top-collections/7d')
const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)

const return_data = []

const table = $('table').children('tbody')
table.each((i, element) => {
    let col_name = $(element).find('a').text()
    return_data.push(col_name)
})
console.log(return_data);
return return_data
```

What I am getting is instead of an array of strings in return_data, I am getting one large string with all of the text in one string, like below:

[One big String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anlMG.png)

I'm guessing it is something to do with how CheerioJS returns data from .each()? I tried saving the result of each .find().text() into its own variable and then inserting that but that didn't fix it.

Comment: Yeah, Cheerio is weird. It is supposed to be exactly like jQuery (server-side) but in fact it's not. `$(element).find('a')` finds all the `<a>` tags in the `<tbody>`, but returns in fact one single Cheerio object, instead of an array of elements like jQuery would. Then you take the `.text()` of that, it gives you one string. Try to iterate the `<a>` with `$(element).find('a').each( ..... push push push )`

Comment: You can also try `$(element).find('a').toArray().forEach( element => ... )`

Comment: That was it, thank you so much for a great and timely answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, Cheerio is a weird clone of jQuery and doesn't behave exactly like it. `$(element).find('a')` finds all the `<a>` but returns one single Cheerio object. You can iterate the links with

```
$(element).find('a').each( ..... push etc )
```

or

```
$(element).find('a').toArray().forEach( element => ... )
```